# Verilog UART has a very long convergence time before working. Why?

Tags: verilog, fpga, uart

I've tried to pull the fast UART implementation found on [this fantastic article](https://jontio.zapto.org/hda1/fpga_intro/50%20Mbps%20UART%20in%20an%20FPGA%20my%20intro%20into%20FPGA.html) and test it myself, but I get random data out of the UART RX that I can't even relate to what is transferred on the serial link. Everything looks just fine to me into the UART RX, the output is just totally wrong: obyte should follow cnt, and it doesn't. Why?
[image]

Does it have something to do with the RX "knowing" where the stop and start bits are? I've always struggled to understand how UARTs such as this one could not get out-of-sync by misinterpreting a bit as a stop or a start. Indeed, it looks like the values given by the RX are affected by the initial value of the counter, somehow.

**Edit:** Thanks to toolic, now I know it does not work for 512 microseconds, and then follows properly - starting with value 0x81 of the counter. Before then, obyte is apparently incremented by 8 every byte instead of by 1, wraps around, is incremented by 4 every byte, and wraps around another time before locking. When I increment cnt by 2 every byte instead of 1, obyte counts by 128, wraps around, then by 64, wraps around, 32, wraps around, 16, wraps around, 8, wraps around, and only then locks in. What's happening? Is this concerning for the reliability of the UART? I'm asking this because if I set cnt to $random%255 every byteClk tick it works.
[image]

Here is the testbench.v code (my code):

```
module testbench();
    //Clock half periods in picoseconds
    localparam HALF_CLK_PERIOD_FAST = 25000;
    localparam HALF_CLK_PERIOD_SLOW = 200000;
    localparam HALF_CLK_PERIOD_BYTES = 2000000;
    
    reg rst; //Reset line
    reg clkFast; //Oversampling
    reg clkSlow; //Bit clock
    reg byteClk; //Byte clock
    reg load; //Load line for TX = every byteClk tick
    
    reg [7:0] cnt; //Test data to send. Is incremented every byteClk tick

    wire serial; //Serial link between TX and RX
    wire [7:0] obyte; //Output byte out of the RX
    wire ovalid; //Data valid strobe for obyte

    uarttx tx
    (
        .clk(clkSlow),
        .txbyte(cnt),
        .txload(load),
        .txd(serial),
        .txholding_reg_full()
    );
    
    uartrx rx
    (
        .clk_slow(clkSlow),
        .clk_fast(clkFast),
        .rxd(serial),
        .obyte(obyte),
        .ovalid(ovalid)
    );

    initial
    begin
        fork
            clkSlow = 1'b0;
            clkFast = 1'b0;
            byteClk = 1'b0;
            cnt = 8'b0; //This initial value seems to have an effect on the performance of the RX
            load = 1'b1; //Start by loading the initial value of cnt
            rst = 1'b0; //Makes a pulse in RST
        join
        #(HALF_CLK_PERIOD_FAST) rst = 1'b1; //Makes a pulse in RST
        #512000000 $stop;
    end 
    
    //Every byteClk tick, the counter is incremented and load is pulled up. 
    always @(posedge byteClk)
    begin
        cnt = cnt+1;
        #(HALF_CLK_PERIOD_FAST) load = 1'b1;
    end
    
    //As soon as the next falling edge of the bit clock, the load line is pulled back down
    always @(negedge clkSlow)
    begin
        if(load)
            load <= 1'b0;
    end
    
    //Clocks generation
    always #HALF_CLK_PERIOD_SLOW clkSlow=~clkSlow;
    always #HALF_CLK_PERIOD_FAST clkFast=~clkFast;
    always #HALF_CLK_PERIOD_BYTES byteClk=~byteClk;
endmodule
```

uart_rx.v (DUT) (I think this is the most evolved version on there):

```
module uartrx
(
    input clk_slow,//baud rate
    input clk_fast,//8*baud rate
    input rxd,//signal in
    output [7:0] obyte,//valid when ovalid is high but will not change till ovalid strobes again
    output ovalid//high for 1 bit to mark a valid obyte
);

//sr for both delay line and syncronizer
parameter SHIFT_REG_LEN=5;
reg [SHIFT_REG_LEN-1:0] shift_reg=0;
always@(posedge clk_fast)
begin
    shift_reg<={shift_reg[SHIFT_REG_LEN-2:0],rxd};
end

//edge detect, counter and lockout
wire neg_edge;//neg edge detect
wire counter_start;//resets/starts the counters
wire idle;//if the line is idle
wire convert;//will go high when valid data arrives
wire Dclk;//data bit clock
wire bit_data;//data offset in future from bit edge
counter_strobe counter_strobe0(clk_fast,counter_start,Dclk);
counter_timeout counter_timeout0(clk_fast,Dclk,counter_start,idle,convert);
assign neg_edge=(shift_reg[SHIFT_REG_LEN-1] & ~shift_reg[SHIFT_REG_LEN-2]);
assign counter_start=(neg_edge&&idle);
assign bit_data=shift_reg[SHIFT_REG_LEN-4];//shift so we are looking at center of symbol rather than edge

//add flipflops to data and convert.
//the strange way of writing this was because
//this gave the best fmax and slack the compiler could
//do as well as making a readable RTL schematic
reg bit_data_latched;
reg convert_latched;
always @(posedge clk_fast)
begin
    if(Dclk)
    begin
        convert_latched<=~convert;
        bit_data_latched<=~bit_data;
    end
end

//convert to parallel
wire [7:0] latched_byte;
wire latched_byte_strobe;
serial_to_parallel #(.N(8)) serial_to_parallel0(clk_slow,(~convert_latched),(~bit_data_latched),latched_byte_strobe,latched_byte);

//for output port assignments
assign obyte=latched_byte;
assign ovalid=latched_byte_strobe;

endmodule

//---------------- submodules begin -------------------

module serial_to_parallel
#(parameter N=8)
(input clk,convert,data_bit,output reg valid_strobe, output reg [N-1:0] data_out);
reg act=0;
initial valid_strobe=0;
reg [N-1:0] abyte;
reg [$clog2(N)-1:0] counter=0;
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    valid_strobe<=0;
    act<=0;
    if(|counter)
    begin
        abyte<={data_bit,abyte[N-1:1]};
        counter<=counter-1;
        act<=1;
    end
    else if(act)
    begin
        valid_strobe<=1;
        data_out<=abyte;
    end
    else if(convert)
    begin
        counter<=(N-1);
        abyte<={data_bit,abyte[N-1:1]};
    end
end
endmodule

//next 2 modules take carefull note of resets. The resets
//must cause the state of the two counters to happen at
//the same time.

//strobe every 8 clks
module counter_strobe(input clk,reset,output reg strobe);
parameter N=3;
reg [N-1:0] count=0;
initial strobe=1;
always@(posedge clk)
begin
    if(reset)
    begin
        strobe<=0;
        count<=1;
    end
    else
    begin
        count<=count+1'b1;
        strobe<=!(|count);
    end
end
endmodule

//timeout after 8 enabled clks plus a bit (IDLE_HOLD_DELAY). timeout causes idle to go high.
//convert goes high on reset and will go low on next enabled clk. when it goes high it's
//time to convert the current 8 bits from serial to parallel
module counter_timeout(input clk,enable,reset,output reg idle,output reg convert);
reg invalid;
parameter N=3;
parameter IDLE_HOLD_DELAY=9;
reg [N-1:0] count=0;
reg [IDLE_HOLD_DELAY-1:0] shift_reg=0;
initial invalid=0;
initial idle=0;
always@(posedge clk)
begin
    {idle,shift_reg}<={shift_reg[IDLE_HOLD_DELAY-1:0],invalid};
    if(reset)
    begin
        {invalid,idle,count}<=0;
        shift_reg<=0;
        convert<=1;
    end
    else if(enable)
    begin
        count<=count+1'b1;
        if(&count)invalid<=1;
        convert<=0;
    end
end
endmodule
```

uart_tx.v (same, I think it's the most evolved version on there) :

```
module uarttx
(
    input clk,//baud rate
    input [7:0] txbyte,
    input txload,
    output reg txd,//signal out
    output reg txholding_reg_full
);
reg [7:0] holding_reg=~0;
reg [7:0] shift_reg=~0;
initial txholding_reg_full=0;
reg shift_reg_empty=1;
reg [3:0] shift_reg_ptr=8;
initial txd=1;
reg txload_last=0;
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    //send either shift reg or idle
    if(shift_reg_ptr<=7)
    begin
        txd<=shift_reg[shift_reg_ptr];
        shift_reg_ptr<=shift_reg_ptr+1;
    end
    else
    begin
        shift_reg_empty<=1;
        txd<=1;
    end
    //if +ve edge of load and hold reg empty then either start sending it or move it to the holding reg
    if((txload&&(!txload_last))&&(!txholding_reg_full))
    begin
        if(shift_reg_empty)
        begin
            shift_reg<=txbyte;
            shift_reg_ptr<=0;
            txd<=0;
            shift_reg_empty<=0;
        end
        else
        begin
            holding_reg<=txbyte;
            txholding_reg_full<=1;
        end
    end
    //else if the shift reg has gone empty then start sending the next holding one if available
    else if(shift_reg_empty&&txholding_reg_full)
    begin
        shift_reg<=holding_reg;
        txholding_reg_full<=0;
        shift_reg_ptr<=0;
        txd<=0;
        shift_reg_empty<=0;
    end
    //for keeping track of +ve edge of txload line
    txload_last<=txload;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: Sorry, updated my question: obyte (out of RX) should follow cnt (input of TX) and it doesn't.

Comment: True. Thanks, I've checked and it starts to follow after 512 microseconds on my side, starting with value 0x81. Updated my question with an edit

Comment: @Mikef: thanks for simulating. serial looks fine to me, there is a 0-start bit, 8 bits of data, then a 1-stop bit before the next 0-start bit. Unless you mean we need another 1 in between?

Comment: I've updated my question with some more information. Looks like obyte skips 7 in 8 values until it wraps around, then skips 3 in 4 values until it wraps around another time, and then only locks in. Does that help?

Comment: "*Does it have something to do with the RX "knowing" where the stop and start bits are?*" -- No, the protocol is asynchronous; frames can arrive at any time.  When the line is at idle (`mark` level) or after a `stop` bit (`mark` level), then a `space` level for the proper bit-time is treated as the `start` bit of a frame.  Besides simply reading each frame from the receiver register, your code should be checking the status register for frame errors, i.e. the `stop` bit was not found where expected (which depends on the frame length).

Comment: A UART can have issues synchronizing with proper frame alignment when presented with a continuous stream of characters/frames that has no idle time at all.  The first/any 1 0 bit sequence (of the continuous bit stream) could be treated as a `idle/stop` `start` bit pattern to begin a frame.